# XSLT: Create combined table from distinct nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I would like to create a combined table that contains data from distinct subnodes in the xml source.

The source is (roughly) the following: Note that I have simplified the example. The "Modes" node is several levels down in a bigger xml document and the "BLOCK" nodes contain more than just the "CODE" children.
The data is gathered from the three distinct nodes Mode1, Mode2 and Mode3. There are more ModeX (X=1..10) nodes in the source document, but they don't make it into this particular table.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="sample.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<root>
  <!-- there are "a lot" more levels between root and Modes -->
  <Modes>
    <Mode1>
      <KOMMENTAR>Header 1</KOMMENTAR>
      <TEST>
        <NUMBER>5</NUMBER>
        <FLAG>0</FLAG>
      </TEST>
      <TEST>
        <NUMBER>6</NUMBER>
        <FLAG>0</FLAG>
      </TEST>
      <TEST>
        <NUMBER>7</NUMBER>
        <FLAG>1</FLAG>
        <BLOCK>
          <CODE>1.7.1 - Message</CODE>
        </BLOCK>
      </TEST>
      <TEST>
        <NUMBER>8</NUMBER>
        <FLAG>1</FLAG>
        <BLOCK>
          <CODE>1.8.1 - Message</CODE>
        </BLOCK>
        <BLOCK>
          <CODE>1.8.2 - Message</CODE>
        </BLOCK>
      </TEST>
      <TEST>
        <NUMBER>9</NUMBER>
        <FLAG>0</FLAG>
        <BLOCK>
          <CODE>1.9.1 - Message</CODE>
        </BLOCK>
      </TEST>
    </Mode1>
    <Mode2>
      <KOMMENTAR>Header 2</KOMMENTAR>
      <TEST>
        <NUMBER>5</NUMBER>
      </TEST>
      <TEST>
        <NUMBER>6</NUMBER>
        <BLOCK>
          <CODE>2.6.1 - Message</CODE>
        </BLOCK>
        <BLOCK>
          <CODE>2.6.2 - Message</CODE>
        </BLOCK>
        <BLOCK>
          <CODE>2.6.2 - Message</CODE>
        </BLOCK>
      </TEST>
      <TEST>
        <NUMBER>7</NUMBER>
        <BLOCK>
          <CODE>2.7.1 - Message</CODE>
        </BLOCK>
      </TEST>
      <TEST>
        <NUMBER>8</NUMBER>
      </TEST>
      <TEST>
        <NUMBER>9</NUMBER>
      </TEST>
    </Mode2>
    <Mode3>
      <KOMMENTAR>Header 3</KOMMENTAR>
      <TEST>
        <NUMBER>5</NUMBER>
      </TEST>
      <TEST>
        <NUMBER>6</NUMBER>
      </TEST>
      <TEST>
        <NUMBER>7</NUMBER>
        <BLOCK>
          <CODE>3.7.1 - Message</CODE>
        </BLOCK>
        <BLOCK>
          <CODE>3.7.2 - Message that spans over several lines</CODE>
        </BLOCK>
      </TEST>
      <TEST>
        <NUMBER>8</NUMBER>
      </TEST>
      <TEST>
        <NUMBER>9</NUMBER>
      </TEST>
    </Mode3>
    <Mode9>
      Contains some other data
    </Mode9>
  </Modes>
</root>
```

The desired output is a table like the following (in HTML):

```
     | Header 1                     | Header 2              | Header 3              |
Test | Flag | Nr. | Message         | Nr. | Message         | Nr. | Message         |
5    | 0    |     |                 |     |                 |     |                 |
6    | 0    |     |                 | 1   | 2.6.1 - Message |     |                 |
     |      |     |                 | 2   | 2.6.2 - Message |     |                 |
     |      |     |                 | 3   | 2.6.3 - Message |     |                 |
7    | 1    | 1   | 1.7.1 - Message | 1   | 2.7.1 - Message | 1   | 3.7.1 - Message |
     |      |     |                 |     |                 | 2   | 3.7.2 - Message |
     |      |     |                 |     |                 |     | that spans over |
     |      |     |                 |     |                 |     | several lines   |
8    | 1    | 1   | 1.8.1 - Message |     |                 |     |                 |
     |      | 2   | 1.8.2 - Message |     |                 |     |                 |
9    | 0    |     |                 |     |                 |     |                 |
```

The best thing I could come up with until now, was to create a sub-table for-each BLOCK underneath TEST. But this looks ugly, since, of course the "Nr." and "Message" headers do not align with the content columns of the sub-tables.

I have read some articles on Muenchian grouping (http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html and other questions on stackoverflow) and tried the examples, but I can't get the keys right for my data.

If somebody could help me with the keys and the outer for-each loop, I think I can handle the rest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are those nodes *really* called `<Mode1>` through `<ModeN>` or is this a "simplification" you applied for the example? Because this makes things more difficult, actually.

Comment: Yes, these nodes are really called `<Mode1>` through `<ModeN>` in the source. No simplification here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If somebody could help me with the keys and the outer for-each loop, I
>   think I can handle the rest.

IMHO, the outer loop is the easy one, and the real problem comes later. Here's how you can do the outer loop:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" version="1.0"/>

<xsl:key name="test" match="TEST" use="NUMBER" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2"/>
                <th colspan="2">Header 1</th>
                <th colspan="2">Header 2</th>
                <th colspan="2">Header 3</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>    
                <th>Test</th>
                <th>Flag</th>
                <th>Nr.</th>
                <th>Message</th>
                <th>Nr.</th>
                <th>Message</th>
                <th>Nr.</th>
                <th>Message</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <xsl:for-each select="(root/Modes/Mode1/TEST | root/Modes/Mode2/TEST | root/Modes/Mode3/TEST)[count(. | key('test', NUMBER)[1]) = 1]">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="NUMBER"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="FLAG"/></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

At this point you will have:

[image]

Now comes the real problem: if you want to have a column that numbers each message and have that number aligned with the adjacent message, you will have to create a separate row for each message that is not the first one in its column. And you will need to calculate the number of messages in each column, and use the maximum of the three as the rowspan value for the first two cells.

Alternatively, you could take the easy way out and do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" version="1.0"/>

<xsl:key name="test" match="TEST" use="NUMBER" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="5%">Test</th>
                <th width="5%">Flag</th>
                <th width="30%">Header 1<br/>Message</th>
                <th width="30%">Header 2<br/>Message</th>
                <th width="30%">Header 3<br/>Message</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <xsl:for-each select="(root/Modes/Mode1/TEST | root/Modes/Mode2/TEST | root/Modes/Mode3/TEST)[count(. | key('test', NUMBER)[1]) = 1]">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="NUMBER"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="FLAG"/></td>
                    <td>
                        <ol>
                            <xsl:for-each select="key('test', NUMBER)[parent::Mode1]/BLOCK">
                                <li>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="CODE"/>
                                </li>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </ol>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <ol>
                            <xsl:for-each select="key('test', NUMBER)[parent::Mode2]/BLOCK">
                                <li>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="CODE"/>
                                </li>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </ol>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <ol>
                            <xsl:for-each select="key('test', NUMBER)[parent::Mode3]/BLOCK">
                                <li>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="CODE"/>
                                </li>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </ol>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to produce:
[image]

which can be further massaged into shape using CSS.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I managed the first part (outer loop) myself, but I'm stuck on this part: _"you will have to create a separate row for each message that is not the first one in its column"_. The numbering of the messages was a bad example on my part. I wanted to simulate data for a second column. The data inside each `BLOCK` are basicall key/value pairs. So I think I'll go with the lists that you suggested, but use <dl> instead, so I can separate "key" and "value" and get everything into shape with css.

Comment: "*I'm stuck on this part:*" Well, as i said, it's not simple at all. Do you want to get into it or are you happy using the workaround? Using `dl` instead of `ol` is a very good idea, IMHO, if you need to present key/value pairs.

Comment: Thanks Michael I'll be happy using the workaround. At some point it's time to say "good is good enough". The workaround solves the problem in an asthetically pleasing way, so I'm fine.